# Save TFS history on local machine

Tags: tfs, team-explorer

We need the entire TFS history to be exported to single/multiple file/s. In there any way to do this without using any third party tools.

Is there any option in the TFS Team Explorer or Administration page to export entire change history by user name?
If not , then what is the easiest solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use TFS PowerShell cmdlets to query the history of a specific source control folder and to filter it by a specific username then download the fiels from those changesets.

```
Get-TfsItemHistory "$/" -recurse -user "username" | % { Get-TfsChangeset $_.Changesetid}
```